# how to go over mongo collection and update strings inside a string field?

Tags: mongodb

my mongo collection model is simple and looks like this:

```
{
  "personId": 24449,
  "address": {
    "city": "6 RUE DE BAE 4765 PARIS"
  }
}
```

I found that in 20k of my doc's there are cases where in the city there is  `\\t` or `\\r`. I fount it out by running:

```
db.people.find({"address.city" : {$regex : ".*\\\\.*"}}})
```

and some of the results looks like this:

```
{ "personId" : 24449, "address" : { "city" : "7 RUE DE LA RHD 90875\\t  PARIS" } }
{ "personId" : 24699, "address" : { "city" : "15 RUE DU DURFIS 343\\t" } }
{ "personId" : 29029, "address" : { "city" : "\\r GOLDOR 00400\\r 7556N HENGELO OV\\r " } }
{ "personId" : 29032, "address" : { "city" : "Wallerbi 10\\r A-410 Bd Leonfeld" } }
{ "personId" : 29033, "address" : { "city" : "Feicubstr 4\\r A-442 Nubach" } }
{ "personId" : 29043, "address" : { "city" : "Schloferstr 60\\r A-201 Groß-Endorf" } }
{ "personId" : 29069, "address" : { "city" : "IMPERIAL HOTEL\\r TEL AVIV\\r RTL\\r \\r \\r WC" } }
```

what command can I run to go over them and remove all the `\\r` and `\\t` in the city..? means to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use db.collection.deleteMany(), [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/#db.collection.deleteMany) is more info.

Comment: Oops, sorry, then you need `updateMany()`, [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db-collection-updatemany) is info.

Comment: i know i will need to use update many but the problem is what i put inside...cause i need to remove ceertain stuff from the field value...just parts of the string

Comment: well, you can use `$trim(aggregation)`. [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/#trim-aggregation) is info.

Comment: im using mongo 3.4.2, cant update to 4 and this feature introduced in 4...